# How can I style cells in react-export-excel?

Tags: excel, reactjs

I am using react-export-excel (latest 0.5.3)
Works fine.

I could not figure out how to style cells? ([link to documentation](https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/blob/master/README.md)

I would like:

1. Extend some cell widths.
2. Set type to numeric or date when appropriate

Here is part of sample code that works well [taken from here](https://github.com/rdcalle/react-export-excel/blob/2ccbf45e8ab5ec3fdc1b5684b3cfd30b34cfcea0/examples/with_custom_download_element.md)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactExport from "react-export-excel";

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;
const ExcelColumn = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelColumn;

const dataSet1 = [
    {
        name: "Johson",
        amount: 30000,
        sex: 'M',
        is_married: true
    },
    {
        name: "Monika",
        amount: 355000,
        sex: 'F',
        is_married: false
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        amount: 250000,
        sex: 'M',
        is_married: false
    },
    {
        name: "Josef",
        amount: 450500,
        sex: 'M',
        is_married: true
    }
];


class Download extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ExcelFile element={<button>Download Data</button>}>
                <ExcelSheet data={dataSet1} name="Employees">
                    <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="name"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="Wallet Money" value="amount"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="Gender" value="sex"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="Marital Status"
                                 value={(col) => col.is_married ? "Married" : "Single"}/>
                </ExcelSheet>

            </ExcelFile>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is that example in the non-forked version of the package that might help you:

https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/blob/master/examples/styled_excel_sheet.md

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactExport from 'react-data-export';
import './App.css';

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;

const multiDataSet = [
    {
        columns: [
            {title: "Headings", width: {wpx: 80}},//pixels width 
            {title: "Text Style", width: {wch: 40}},//char width 
            {title: "Colors", width: {wpx: 90}},
        ],
        data: [
            [
                {value: "H1", style: {font: {sz: "24", bold: true}}},
                {value: "Bold", style: {font: {bold: true}}},
                {value: "Red", style: {fill: {patternType: "solid", fgColor: {rgb: "FFFF0000"}}}},
            ],
            [
                {value: "H2", style: {font: {sz: "18", bold: true}}},
                {value: "underline", style: {font: {underline: true}}},
                {value: "Blue", style: {fill: {patternType: "solid", fgColor: {rgb: "FF0000FF"}}}},
            ],
            [
                {value: "H3", style: {font: {sz: "14", bold: true}}},
                {value: "italic", style: {font: {italic: true}}},
                {value: "Green", style: {fill: {patternType: "solid", fgColor: {rgb: "FF00FF00"}}}},
            ],
            [
                {value: "H4", style: {font: {sz: "12", bold: true}}},
                {value: "strike", style: {font: {strike: true}}},
                {value: "Orange", style: {fill: {patternType: "solid", fgColor: {rgb: "FFF86B00"}}}},
            ],
            [
                {value: "H5", style: {font: {sz: "10.5", bold: true}}},
                {value: "outline", style: {font: {outline: true}}},
                {value: "Yellow", style: {fill: {patternType: "solid", fgColor: {rgb: "FFFFFF00"}}}},
            ],
            [
                {value: "H6", style: {font: {sz: "7.5", bold: true}}},
                {value: "shadow", style: {font: {shadow: true}}},
                {value: "Light Blue", style: {fill: {patternType: "solid", fgColor: {rgb: "FFCCEEFF"}}}}
            ]
        ]
    }
];

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ExcelFile element={<button>Download Data With Styles</button>}>
                    <ExcelSheet dataSet={multiDataSet} name="Organization"/>
                </ExcelFile>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The library comes as well with a numFmt attribute for cells, here you can see the different values:

```
/* ExcelNumFormat */
type ExcelNumFormat = "0" | "0.00%" | "0.0%" | "0.00%;\\(0.00%\\);\\-;@" | "m/dd/yy" | string;
```

https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/blob/master/types/types.md

Comment: You are correct. Thanks. Just emphasize that you must use ```                    <ExcelSheet dataSet={multiDataSet} name="Organization"/>
```
dataset and not *data* in ExcelSheet props. Not the best design...